# Не получается получить код html из интернета

Tags: android, java

Всем привет, я тут новенький.

Я пытался получить тело html с урл (сейчас у меня у меня настроено на локалхост), но не получается это сделать. Я не получаю ошибок и ничего такого... inputStream всегда = -1. Если я пытаюсь использовать свой код для получения html с google.com , то там всё нормально. Куча данных выливается в логкате и я в принципе был бы доволен. Но вот с одного адреса я никак не могу получить данные.

Код очень простой:

```
URL url = new URL("http://217.133.78.74:81/realtime.txt");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

index.html

```
<HTML><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"></head><body>some text bla bla bla</body></html>
```

Всё, что нужно, - отобразить этот код с индекса в моей аппшке. (

p.s. Создал аналогичную тему на стэке. Там токо глупые подсказки дают, то добавить протокол или поместить его в ассет. Но мне нужно именно с интернета (в коде примерного ввида ссылка и будет. Таким же адресом с цифр, портом и файлом в конце  %) )
Пожалуйста, если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, опишите как ее исправить! Буду очень благодарен.

С ув. peterDroid :)

**UPD** ошибка которая наконецто начала появлятся.. надеюсь проблема в ней.

```
01-25 22:31:08.374: W/System.err(1021): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
01-25 22:31:08.374: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
01-25 22:31:08.394: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-25 22:31:08.394: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-25 22:31:08.402: W/System.err(1021):     at fuckintestpackage.com.FuckintestActivity.onCreate(FuckintestActivity.java:40)
01-25 22:31:08.424: W/System.err(1021):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-25 22:31:08.424: W/System.err(1021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-25 22:31:08.424: W/System.err(1021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-25 22:31:08.424: W/System.err(1021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-25 22:31:08.424: W/System.err(1021):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-25 22:31:08.424: W/System.err(1021):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 22:31:08.424: W/System.err(1021):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-25 22:31:08.424: W/System.err(1021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-25 22:31:08.424: W/System.err(1021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 22:31:08.463: W/System.err(1021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-25 22:31:09.753: W/System.err(1021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-25 22:31:09.753: W/System.err(1021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-25 22:31:09.753: W/System.err(1021):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 22:31:09.753: W/System.err(1021): Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
01-25 22:31:09.793: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:93)
01-25 22:31:09.793: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
01-25 22:31:09.793: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
01-25 22:31:09.793: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
01-25 22:31:09.793: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
01-25 22:31:09.904: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
01-25 22:31:09.941: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
01-25 22:31:09.941: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:410)
01-25 22:31:09.962: W/System.err(1021):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-25 22:31:09.962: W/System.err(1021):     ... 16 more
```

Кстати, с тем кодом что привел выше, эта ошибка не воспроизводится.. и ответ от сервера всё так же стоит : -1

```
getResponseCode = -1 ;
```

Этот код который я в данный момент тестю/изменяю/извращаю(найден на просторах интернета)

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  WebView wbs = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
  WebSettings wb = wbs.getSettings();
  Log.v("User AGENT","user agent : "+wb.getUserAgentString());
  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://217.133.78.74:81/realtime.txt");
  httpget.addHeader("User-Agent", ""+wb.getUserAgentString());//люди пишут что иногда ////добавление юзер агента помогало.. мне пока не помогает, хотя мб я не правильно его ///добавляю
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputstream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader bufferedreader =
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
                StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String currentline = null;
                while ((currentline = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringbuilder.append(currentline + "\n");
                }
                String result = stringbuilder.toString();
                Log.v("HTTP REQUEST",result);
                inputstream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

В варианте от [Moazzam Khan](http://moazzam-khan.com) данного кода, используется следующий набор опций:

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Для чтения буфера:

```
String str;
String content;
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8192);

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    buff.append(str);
}
content = new String(buff.toString().getBytes(), "cp1251");
```

Пока не жалуюсь, работает везде и со всем.

Comment: Боюсь прямо спрашивать, а по ссылке телефон/пад/что там у вас может зайти?

Comment: Т.е. другие браузеры телефона, использующие (в основном) тот же класс для подключения могут видеть эту ссылку, а ваш нет?

Что значит с "портом подобного вида"?

Comment: я имел ввиду "ссылку" подобно локалхосту андроида с портом ( как указано в исходнике который я предоставил), Немного не понял вас про браузеры : В брауезере андроида я открывал эту ссылку, но с кода я не могу ее открыть (конечное же я не пробовал через вебвиев) только http

Comment: ВЫ можете написать ссылку полностью, которую вы пробуете?

Comment: Вот http://217.133.78.74:81/realtime.txt . Я еще подправил пост первый(добавил логкат). Сейчас наконецто получаю ошибку CLientProtocolException  надеюсь вы всё таки поможете (( А то уже кучу всего перепробовал((

Comment: @PeterDroid, да уж, интересная "фича". Когда порт задан таким вот образом, работать отказывается на смарте, хотя в JRE работает

Comment: @Dex 
Так что никак не решить это ?(

Comment: @PeterDroid, ваш хост больше не работает?

Comment: уже нет (. Друг помог (хотя и кривовато) через яху какой то там парсер. Тот парсер создает мини хмл файл и также ссылку новую.. пока пробую юзать это . Жаль там количество запросов ограничено

Answer (score 0):

Ну а что вы хотите если ваша ссылка не работает? Попробуйте сами воткните на http://10.0.2.2:80/index.html - если браузер не кажет как может аппа показать?

Comment: Это самый лучший комментарий который  я когда либо видел.Ссылка рабочая, а та которая приведена здесь - была приведена для примера. Рабочая ссылка тоже ввиде ip с портом